# Ruby on Rails - Unable to see the console message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably a really silly questions, but I'm a Ruby on Rails newbie...

If in on of the .rb files I write something like

```
puts "hello"
```

Where can I view the output? I'm running rails console in the shell and the message is not appearing when the code runs. It is also not appearing in the Chrome console.

Thank you!

**EDIT** I guess there is a problem in my code then, I have:

login.html.erb:

```
<% @page_title = "UserAuth | Login" -%>
<div class= "Sign_Form">
  <h1>Log in</h1>
    <%= form_tag "/login", :sessions => :login_attempt do %>
    <p>Username or Email:</br> <%= text_field_tag(:username_or_email) %></p> 
    <p>Password:</br> <%= password_field_tag :login_password %></p> 
    <%= submit_tag("Log In") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

session_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:home, :profile, :setting]
before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:login, :login_attempt]
  def login
    #Login Form
  end
  def login_attempt
      authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email],params[:login_password])
      puts "authorized_user " + authorized_user + "\n" # this does not run
      if authorized_user
        session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
        flash[:alert] = "Wow Welcome again, you logged in as #{authorized_user.username}"
        redirect_to(:action => 'home')
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Invalid Username or Password"
        flash[:color]= "invalid"
        render "login"  
      end
    end
    def logout
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to :action => 'login'
    end
end
```

Comment: one of the .rb file? which file?

Comment: it will display/show on console(rails console)

Comment: I don't see it in the server console or rails console, I guess the line of code does not run when the form is submitted. I edited and added my code, do you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see it in `server console` where you ran `rails server` command

Comment: I guess the line of code does not run when the form is submitted. I edited and added my code, do you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you put it. For example in a model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Methods
  def hello
     puts "hello"
  end

end
```

When you run the rails console and have a user you can call user.hello which will output the "hello" to your rails console. When you are running a server with the `rails server` command,  you will see in in the same window as where you started the server.